# How to Create a VPN server on an iPhone or join another machine to a LAN via the web

Tags: ssh, vpn, proxy, iphone, jailbreak

Is it possible to create a VPN server on an iPhone so that I can connect to it with Linux box and bring the Linux box onto the iPhone’s LAN?

I’ve been looking all day and everything available for iOS seems to be a client. Jail breaking isn’t an issue.

Any other alternatives to a VPN to bring a Linux box over the web onto the iPhones LAN are also very helpful. Not direct SSH as I need to use software on the Linux box. Could I use proxies or OpenSSH?

Comment: No;  What is possible is you connect to a VPN server and then create a Hotspot. Apple wouldn't approve a VPN server on the App Store.

Comment: A hotspot won't help with this, I'm trying to bring an out of the network Linux box, that isn't located near the iPhone onto the LAN.

Comment: You wanted to connect a Linux box to the iphone, using a Hotspot iPhone feature, would make that possible.  At the end of the day this question does not seem to be on topic at Superuser.

Comment: Which stack exchange section would you suggest?

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do (or for that matter why you need it to be an OpenVPN server, not a client).

Comment: @davidgo I want to connect the Linux Box to the iPhone over the internet so that it creates a virtual network/tunnel so that the linux box can 'join' the network that the iPhone is part of. Is it possible to do that with both the iPhone and linux box as 'clients'?